# Element XMLZONE is undefined in REQUEST

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I'm getting the error `Element XMLZONE is undefined in REQUEST` a few dozen times a day.

**PageDisplay.cfm** calls **request.xmlzone** which is set via the page **ZoneManager.cfm**, using the following (cut down) code

```
<cfscript> 
variables.aZoneInfo = XmlSearch(application.xmlZones, "//zone[position() = 1]"); 
try { 
     request.xmlZone = ToString(variables.aZoneInfo[1]); 
} 
catch(any expt)
{ 
     variables.objZoneDAO = CreateObject("component", "#application.sComponentDir#ZoneDAO").init(application.sDSN); 
     variables.objZoneDAO.Read(variables.objZone, 1); } 
</cfscript>
```

Now, the XML will never ever change so is it worth adding the XML file/node to **PageDisplay.cfm** as a variable? I'd also like to know why it fails - any reason why?

Thanks,

JJ

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the call to `ToString(variables.aZoneInfo[1]);` fails, then `request.xmlZone` won't get set.  It's doubtful `toString()` itself will fail, but if `variables.aZoneInfo` isn't an array with at least one element, then that'll cause you grief.  You should be checking this, rather than assuming it.

If it's essential that `request.xmlZone` is set, then you need to do more in your catch block than what you're currently doing.  At the very least you should be logging the exception that was caught, so that when you go "I wonder why that happened?" you have a log to refer to.

I suspect your application is timing out, and when you're doing your `xmlSearch()`, `application.xmlZones` doesn't contain what you think it contains. But that's a guess.

Comment: Thanks - I will look into this. At the moment, I'm using `cfxml` to set a variable and using that instead given that the XML will never change (I have took this site on by the way - it's not my own work!)